# How to upload directory from linux

Tags: linux, centos, directory

I'm using Centos 7 Server.

I do have specific directory which am looking to automatically upload everything inside it each time the size of it changed in order to save a copy of it all time.

so i would like to know what is the best service shall i use and i will highly appreciate the usage of it.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

`lsyncd` is your tool for this. It uses Linux `inotify` mechanism to detect changes as they occur on filesystem, and then it automatically launches `rsync` to synchronize files to the other system.

Another alternative is to use a cluster filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I'd use rsync to sync between the two folders.

You can set a crontab job to run every hour or so, and sync between the two folders, rsync will identify automatically if one folder is not updated with the other one.

[This article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps) will help you understand and give you the commands you need to use in order to implement your solution.